# tabularray inside tcolorbox "breaks page" continuously

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox, tabularray

[image]

I'm trying to put a `longtblr` inside a `tcolorbox` but it seems that the tabularray package redefines `\pagebreak` and `\nopagebreak` as mentioned in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646495/tcolorbox-inside-tabularray-leading-to-0s/646499#646499), I'm not into manipulation of commands and tried both answers but it keeps behaving like the picture, How can I achieve a continuous table ?

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        nobeforeafter,
        title={Hallazgos sobre la eficiencia del destilador solar},
        colback=white,
        colframe=blue!10,
        coltitle=black
    ]
        \lipsum[1]
        \begin{longtblr}[
            caption = {Pérdidas de un destilador solar},
            label = {table:perdidas_malik}
        ]{
            colspec = {X c},
            hlines,
            vlines,
            row{odd} = {bg=green!20!blue!20},
            row{1} = {
                bg = green!80!blue!60,
                fg=white,
                font =  \large\bfseries
            },
            rowhead = 1,
            rows={m}
        }
            Motivo & Pérdida \\ 
            % Table body%
            Pérdida de calor por radiación desde la superficie del agua salina a la cubierta & \qty{26}{\percent} \\ 
            Pérdida de calor por el reflejo de la luz & \qty{11}{\percent} \\ 
            Pérdida por reevaporación del destilado & \qty{10}{\percent} \\ 
            Pérdida por el calor absorbido por el vidrio & \qty{5}{\percent} \\ 
            Pérdidas por suelo y bordes & \qty{2}{\percent} \\ 
            Otras pérdidas & \qty{7}{\percent}
        \end{longtblr}
    \end{tcolorbox} 
\end{document}
```

It works properly in Overleaf but I think it may be because package version

Comment: And you question is: ... ? (Version check, bypass, workaround, alternatives ...)

Comment: The other question is unrelated,  that was about a tcolorbox inside a tabular and not the other way round.

Comment: @MS-SPO a workaround: "How can I achieve a continuos table ?"

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I considered important to include that question, because it gives a hint that the problem may be caused by the redefinition of those commands

Comment: This code show one table into a tcolorbox for me. I'm on windows with an updated MikTeX.